# Finding biggest negative submatrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, submatrix

I want find the biggest submatrix which contains only negative numbers in a matrix, for example:

In

```
[[1,  -9, -2,   8,  6,  1],    
 [8,  -1,-11,  -7,  6,  4],    
 [10, 12, -1,  -9, -12, 14],    
 [8, 10, -3,  -5,  17,  8],    
 [6,  4, 10, -13, -16, 19]]
```

the biggest submatrix containing only negative numbers is

```
[[-11, -7],
 [-1, -9],
 [-3,-5]]
```

(left upper corner coordinates: 1,2, right lower corner coordinates: 3,3).

What's the most effective way to do it?

Comment: Can the solution matrix contain zeros? Since 0 can be seen as both a positive and a negative number ...

Comment: No, in this case 0 is seen as a positive number.

Comment: What does "biggest" mean here?

Comment: @slider Probably the biggest subarea.

Comment: A brute-force algorithm would be quite easy to write - however I guess that there are smarter algorithms for this problem. Does the solution have to be fast?

Comment: In terms of dimensions, the one where `-11` is the top left corner is the biggest. If it's the sum of elements, then the single element matrix `[[-1]]` is the biggest.

Comment: @IvanHlivan your coordinates and answer matrix do not match.

Comment: @slider sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A brute force solution. Will work, but may be considered too slow for a bigger matrix:

```
mOrig = [[1,  -9, -2,   8,  6,  1],
    [8,  -1,-11,  -7,  6,  4],
    [10, 12, -1,  -9, -12, 14],
    [8, 10, -3,  -5,  17,  8],
    [6,  4, 10, -13, -16, 19]]

# reduce the problem
# now we have a matrix that contains only 0 and 1
# at the place where there was a negative number
# there is now a 1 and at the places where a positive
# number had been there is now a 0. 0s are considered
# to be negative numbers, if you want to change this,
# change the x < 0 to x <= 0.
m = [[1 if x < 0 else 0 for x in z] for z in mOrig]

# now we have the problem to find the biggest submatrix
# consisting only 1s.

# first a function that checks if a submatrix only contains 1s
def containsOnly1s(m, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    for i in range(x1, x2):
        for j in range(y1, y2):
            if m[i][j] == 0:
                return False
    return True

def calculateSize(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)

best = (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
for x1 in range(len(m)):
    for y1 in range(len(m[0])):
        for x2 in range(x1, len(m)):
            for y2 in range(y1, len(m[0])):
                if containsOnly1s(m, x1, y1, x2, y2):
                    sizeOfSolution = calculateSize(x1, y1, x2, y2)
                    if best[4] < sizeOfSolution:
                        best = (x1, y1, x2, y2, sizeOfSolution)

for x in range(best[0], best[2]):
    print("\t".join([str(mOrig[x][y]) for y in range(best[1], best[3])]))
```

Will output

```
-11 -7
-1  -9
-3  -5
```

In case something else is meant with "biggest submatrix", the only function that needs to get changed is the following:

```
def calculateSize(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)
```

which is calculating the size of a submatrix.

**Edit 1 ... first speedup**

```
best = (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
for x1 in range(len(m)):
    for y1 in range(len(m[0])):
        if m[x1][y1] == 1: # The starting point must contain a 1
            for x2 in range(x1 + 1, len(m)): # actually can start with x1 + 1 here
                for y2 in range(y1 + 1, len(m[0])):
                    if containsOnly1s(m, x1, y1, x2, y2):
                        sizeOfSolution = calculateSize(x1, y1, x2, y2)
                        if best[4] < sizeOfSolution:
                            best = (x1, y1, x2, y2, sizeOfSolution)
                    else:
                        # There is at least one 0 in the matrix, so every greater
                        # matrix will also contain this 0
                        break
```

**Edit 2**

Ok, after converting the matrix into a matrix of 0 and 1 (as I do via the line `m = [[1 if x < 0 else 0 for x in z] for z in mOrig]` the problem is the same as what is called `the maximal rectangle problem` in literature. So I googled a bit about known algorithms for this kind of problem and came across this site here http://www.drdobbs.com/database/the-maximal-rectangle-problem/184410529 which is describing a very fast algorithm to solve this kind of problem. To summarize the points of this website, the algorithm is exploiting the structure. This can be done by using a stack in order to remember the structure profile which allows us to recalculate the width in case a narrow rectangle gets reused when an wider one gets closed.

Comment: This works perfectly, but too slow for bigger matrix.

Comment: We're talking about matrix of dimensions 5000x5000... and optimal time of solution would be less than 60 seconds. Though, I know.

Comment: @IvanHlivan From my understanding of the problem this should be possible. I know of a very fast algorithm that is doing something similar in 1d not in 2d. So I only need to twist my head how I can do the same in 2d ...

Comment: @IvanHlivan Can you provide one 5000x5000 matrix, so that I can check the time on my computer?

Comment: @IvanHlivan The algorithm mentioned in Edit 2 should be fast enough, you only need to convert it from pseudo code into the programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my pretty fast solution using convolutions from OpenCV. Usage of float32 is required as it is much faster than integers. Takes 135 ms for 1000 x 1000 matrix on my 2 cores. There's space for further code optimization though.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

data = """1 -9 -2 8 6 1
8 -1 -11 -7 6 4
10 12 -1 -9 -12 14
8 10 -3 -5 17 8
6 4 10 -13 -16 19"""

# matrix = np.random.randint(-128, 128, (1000, 1000), dtype=np.int32)
matrix = np.int32([line.split() for line in data.splitlines()])

def find_max_kernel(matrix, border=cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED):
    max_area = 0
    mask = np.float32(matrix < 0)
    ones = np.ones_like(mask)
    conv_x = np.zeros_like(mask)
    conv_y = np.zeros_like(mask)
    max_h, max_w = mask.shape
    for h in range(1, max_h + 1):
        cv2.filter2D(mask, -1, ones[:h, None, 0], conv_y, (0, 0), 0, border)
        for w in range(1, max_w + 1):
            area = h * w
            if area > max_area:
                cv2.filter2D(conv_y, -1, ones[None, 0, :w], conv_x, (0, 0), 0, border)
                if conv_x.max() == area:
                    max_area, shape = area, (h, w)
                else:
                    if w == 1:
                        max_h = h - 1
                    if h == 1:
                        max_w = w - 1
                    break
        if h >= max_h:
            break
    cv2.filter2D(mask, -1, np.ones(shape, np.float32), conv_x, (0, 0), 0, border)
    p1 = np.array(np.unravel_index(conv_x.argmax(), conv_x.shape))
    p2 = p1 + shape - 1            
    return p1, p2

print(*find_max_kernel(matrix), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a function that executes in much less than a second for a 5000x5000 matrix. It relies only on basic np-functions.

It could be improved  by returning the first index instead of all indices. Several other optimizations can be done but for many uses it is fast enough.

```py
from numpy import roll, where
def gidx(X):
    Wl = X & roll(X, 1, axis=1)
    T = X & Wl & roll(X, -1, axis=1)
    if T[1:-1][1:-1].any():
        N = T & roll(T, -1, axis=0) & roll(T, 1, axis=0)
        if N.any(): return gidx(N)
    W = Wl & roll(Wl, 1, axis=0)
    if W.any(): return where(W)
    return where(X)

#%% Example
import numpy as np
#np.random.seed(0)
M = 100
X = np.random.randn(M, M) - 2

X0 = (X < 0)
X0[[0, -1]], X0[:, [0, -1]] = False, False
jx, kx = gidx(X0)
```